# Как увеличить значение одного поля одним запросом

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Не могу найти способ реализовать операцию увеличения поля не производя перед этим выборку, то есть нужно сделать следующее:

```
        public void MakeTurn(int userId)
        {
            var user = _storageContext.Users.Find(userId);
            user.CurrentTurn++;
            _storageContext.SaveChanges();
        }

public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CurrentTurn { get; set; }
    }
```

Другими словами, я бы хотел чтобы ef сгенерировал похожий запрос:

```
UPDATE Users SET CurrentTurn = CurrentTurn+ 1 WHERE id=1
```

Comment: Что вы увеличивать будете, если не прочитаете юзера из бд?

Comment: Я надеялся, что есть возможность сделать так чтобы  ef сгенерировал что-нибудь вроде этого UPDATE Users SET CurrentTurn = CurrentTurn+ 1 WHERE id=1

Comment: Ага, теперь понял вашу мысль, но как это сделать не смогу вам подсказать. Не приходилось делать такие апдейты с EF.

Comment: Вы хотите ORM framework использовать не как ORM. Это забавно. :)  Проще всего напрямую тогда обратиться к базе с запросом в сыром виде. Что-то типа context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query)

Comment: Это не какая-то запредельная функциональность, которая совершенно не свойственна orm, к тому же, на сколько я могу судить, в EF6 такая возможность была. И мне тут посоветовали библиотеку EF+, которая позволяет реализовать такие запросы поверх EF, хотя конечно ради одной такой операции я её использовать не буду.